# This Binary Search Tree is Not Balanced, Correct?

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

Trying to wrap my head around the definition of a balanced binary search tree. The image of the below tree is not balanced because Node 1 and Node 6 are different heights (as well as differences > 1 in other nodes).

Is this correct?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Instead of asking a yes / no question ("is this correct?") you might want to ask for a definition or explanation of _"balancing"_ in regards to binary search trees. (it's also perfectly fine to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you already know it)